# Beamer is showing uncompleted words

Tags: beamer, babel-french

I have problem in beamer, I am writing in frensh and when I write some words, they are qualified as wrong and in the compilation it gives uncompleat words for example I write "finiment" which means finitely it gives "niment"
thanks for helping.

Comment: Do you maybe use some spell checker software? If so, what happens if you disable it and recompile the document?

Comment: no I don't use any of that

Comment: Please make a minimal working example which shows us which fonts and encodings you use.